# Eigenvalues of elliptic operator analytic with respect to a parameter

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, linear-pde

I am interested when one can say the eigenvalues of an elliptic operator 
are real analytic with respect to a parameter.  In particular I have seen many people say the first eigenvalue is analytic but for the higher eigenvalues there can be problems (when the eigenvalues cross).

Let me state the setting I am in now.  Consider 
$$-\Delta w_p(r) = g(r) w_p(r) + (w_p(r))^p$$ in $B_1$  (the unit ball in $ R^N$)  with $ w_p(1)=0$.    Here $ p>1$ is a parameter and we assume $g(r)$ is analytic in $r$.  We assume for $p$ in some given interval we have a unique radial solution which I am writing as $ w_p$ and we assume this solution is radial nondegenerate.    I am interested when I can say the solution truly is nondegenerate (ie. want the kernel of the linearized operator to be trivial;  it is trivial over the space of radial functions by assumption).

So what I would like is that the eigenvalues $\mu_k(p)$ are analytic with respect to $p$.  Lets assume we are looking at the second eigenvalue.   Since we have symmetry i assume the second eigenvalue will have large multiplicity (maybe) and hence we shouldn't have to worry about any crossings of eigenvalues. 
I realize this question isn't well posed;  but any comments would be greatly appreciated.

I am aware of the paper ''Real analyticity and non-degeneracy''  by Norman Dancer in Mathematische Annalen.

Comment: This looks like it might be a question where one starts with T. Kato, *Perturbation Theory of Linear Operators*

Comment: @ChristianRemling Touche; I have edited my comment :)

Comment: @Neal   Thanks for the reference I will take a look.